# Creating horizontal legend bar in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector, legend, progress

[image]

I tried to design this beautiful legend style with my vector data (by overlapping each legend framebox) in ArcMap, but I can't find a good model that fit with

Does anyone have any idea?

---

[image]

Here is another example to deal with.

PS: I want to do that with a vector shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post, [Raster enhancement: The horizontal legend](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/data-management/raster-enhancement-the-horizontal-legend/?rmedium=blogs_esri_com&rsource=/esri/arcgis/2011/04/27/raster-enhancement-the-horizontal-legend/), which shows how to do this. I tried it and within a couple of minutes, I got 90% there.

What I got:

[image]

I think the only thing you'll need to do, is adjust the label frequency, and override the patch size to make it longer.

Comment: Thanks Fezter ! But I want to do that with vector shapefile. I don't used to work with raster data. Thanks anyway.